# Where should I put secrets if I'm using embeddedServer?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have google oauth credentials, and a google application password to send emails, I wanna know where should I put this information if I'm using `embeddedServer`

If you are using  `EngineMain`, Ktor docs are clear (use `application.conf` or `application.yaml`), but there are no answer for when you are using `embeddedServer`. I don't wanna put this information in my code.

I tried to create `application.conf` in the `resources` folder and then retrieve the data using:

```
val googleClientId = environment.config.propertyOrNull("ktor.deployment.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")?.getString() ?: ""
```

However, the function always returns `null`

Anyone knows where to put secrets when you are using `embeddedServer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your secrets through the environment variables to your application or use an external secrets storage. Storing secrets in a configuration file isn't safe. To use a configuration file with the `embeddedServer`, pass an environment as the second argument:

```
val env = applicationEngineEnvironment {
    connector {
        port = 8080
    }
    config = ApplicationConfig("application.conf")
    module {
        routing {
            get {
                call.respondText { application.environment.config.propertyOrNull("ktor.deployment.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")!!.getString() }
            }
        }
    }
}
val server = embeddedServer(Netty, env)
server.start(wait = true)
```

Also, you can use a configuration instance not bound to the application:

```
val config = ApplicationConfig("application.conf")
val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
    routing {
        get {
            call.respondText { config.propertyOrNull("ktor.deployment.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")!!.getString() }
        }
    }
}
server.start(wait = true)
```